# I'm having trouble with an error message after trying to install spotify

Tags: spotify

I need to install Spotify. But after trying so I get the error message:

```
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How do I get this error message to go away?

Comment: Please share the content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list It sounds like the syntax is not correct.

Comment: I opened it in plain text editor and nothing shows.

Comment: That's inconsistent with the error message. Please make sure that you entered the right path. You can also go to the file system root `/` and navigate through the directories and files with the mouse pointer.